# Pyright LSP, leading spaces appears as "&nbsp;" in hover

Tags: neovim, lsp, python, pyright

I am using pyright LSP with the neovim (0.10.0-dev), and am seeing any *leading* spaces in docstrings replaced by `&nbsp;`. For example, see the attached image:

[image]

As far as I can tell it seems very similar to this issue: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/issues/936 . Unfortunately, from that issue I can't determine how the problem was rectified. I'm already using `nvim-cmp` (the successor to `nvim-compe`), so am assuming that this isn't the problem.

I am using `mason`, and `mason-lspconfig`, and am initialising pyright as follows. (And calling `setup` with purely default arguments gives the same result.)

```lua
        require("lspconfig").pyright.setup {
            settings = {
                pyright = {
                    -- Use Ruff for import organisation
                    disableOrganizeImports = true,
                },
            }
        }
```

So far I've tried, without success, to

- find a way to tell pyright LSP to return plaintext rather than HTML format
- find a way to intercept the string that neovim receives from the LSP, and use a lua function to replace `"&nbsp;"` with `" "` before it gets rendered   (which would be VERY hacky but better than nothing!)

Does someone know any likely causes of this issue?